# Does Breeze work with Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, table-per-hierarchy

I'm trying to plug BreezeJs into an existing datastructure and getting an error in the meta data fetch. I can replicate this by adding the following to the CarBones sample

```
namespace CarBones.Models
{
  public abstract class VanBase
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
  }

  public class BasicVan : VanBase
  {

  }

  public class LiveriedVan : VanBase
  {
    public string Livery { get; set; }
  }
}
```

then in the context

```
 public DbSet<VanBase> Vans { get; set; }
```

This is enough to trigger

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propertyRef' of undefined breeze.debug.js 5224
```

Can I not use TPH in this way with Breeze? Yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: As of v 1.3.1 Breeze now DOES support inheritance.

Breeze does not **yet** support inheritance.  It is on our list though, so please vote for it on the Breeze User Voice  [here](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3083057-support-inheritence-in-the-object-model) so that we can correctly prioritize the variously requested additional breeze features.  We take this venue very seriously.

Comment: Right now it's 3rd on our list, right after native OData write support and examples showing how to use breeze with non-.NET backends.